# change the displayed name of the minecraft version

Tags: json, minecraft

i'm trying to change the displayed name of the minecraft version 'cause of some server has plugin which detects if a client is running forge by checking its version, i tried to decompile several .class files in search of that settings but i didn't found it, [here the screen of what "displayed version" i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8fec.jpg).

the only thing that i found is this "id", but if i change it i only get minecraft crashing.

```
{
    "_comment_": [
        "Please do not automate the download and installation of Forge.",
        "Our efforts are supported by ads from the download page.",
        "If you MUST automate this, please consider supporting the project through https://www.patreon.com/LexManos/"
    ],
    "id": "1.16.5-forge-36.2.0",
    "time": "2021-07-22T01:48:10+00:00",
    "releaseTime": "2021-07-22T01:48:10+00:00",
    "type": "release",
    "mainClass": "cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher",
    "inheritsFrom": "1.16.5",
    "logging": {
        
    },
```

pls help, this is getting me mad.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a client brand. Vanilla Minecraft uses `vanilla`, Forge uses `fml,forge`, Lunar client uses `Lunarclient:LunarVersionNumber`, etc. I don't know about 1.16.5, but in 1.8.9 the class which is used for getting the client brand is `net.minecraft.client.ClientBrandRetriever` (It would be similar to 1.8.9). You would need to use mixins or another way of manipulating code at runtime to modify this.

Comment: i tried to check that file, but is already set on "vanilla", i put the code here:
`package net.minecraft.client;

public class ClientBrandRetriever {
  public static String getClientModName() {
    return "vanilla";
  }
}`
this is the ClientBrandRetriever.class located in .minecraft\versions\1.16.5-forge-36.2.0\1.16.5-forge-36.2.0\net\minecraft\client, this the folder of the unpacked .jar file

Comment: @nicolas200221 I'm pretty sure forge is just like a library to Minecraft. It runs on top of Minecraft's code. You would need to create a forge mod that edits the client brand. When I view it in the MDK I can see that it edits the brand to 'fml,forge'.

Comment: ok i never did minecraft mod, i know java very well, can you help me telling what i've to do? i think that i've to override the method getClientModName of the class ClientBrandRetriever somehow, right? or if i can, only modify and recompile the library where forge does it

Comment: @nicolas200221 I'm not too sure, the easiest way imo would be to create a mod

Answer (score 0):

ok i actually found something while trying making the mod, i found this 2 .class file.
Forge's ClientBrandRetriever.class

```
package net.minecraft.client;

import net.minecraftforge.api.distmarker.Dist;
import net.minecraftforge.api.distmarker.OnlyIn;

@OnlyIn(Dist.CLIENT)
public class ClientBrandRetriever {
   public static String getClientModName() {
      return net.minecraftforge.fml.BrandingControl.getClientBranding();
   }
}
```

and this called BrandingControl.class

```
/*
 * Minecraft Forge
 * Copyright (c) 2016-2021.
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation version 2.1
 * of the License.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 */

package net.minecraftforge.fml;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import net.minecraft.resources.IResourceManager;
import net.minecraft.resources.IResourceManagerReloadListener;
import net.minecraftforge.client.ForgeHooksClient;
import net.minecraftforge.versions.forge.ForgeVersion;
import net.minecraftforge.versions.mcp.MCPVersion;


public class BrandingControl
{
    private static List<String> brandings;
    private static List<String> brandingsNoMC;
    private static List<String> overCopyrightBrandings;

    private static void computeBranding()
    {
        if (brandings == null)
        {
            ImmutableList.Builder<String> brd = ImmutableList.builder();
            brd.add("Forge " + ForgeVersion.getVersion());
            brd.add("Minecraft " + MCPVersion.getMCVersion());
            brd.add("MCP " + MCPVersion.getMCPVersion());
            int tModCount = ModList.get().size();
            brd.add(ForgeI18n.parseMessage("fml.menu.loadingmods", tModCount));
            brandings = brd.build();
            brandingsNoMC = brandings.subList(1, brandings.size());
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getBrandings(boolean includeMC, boolean reverse)
    {
        computeBranding();
        if (includeMC) {
            return reverse ? Lists.reverse(brandings) : brandings;
        } else {
            return reverse ? Lists.reverse(brandingsNoMC) : brandingsNoMC;
        }
    }

    private static void computeOverCopyrightBrandings() {
        if (overCopyrightBrandings == null) {
            ImmutableList.Builder<String> brd = ImmutableList.builder();
            if (ForgeHooksClient.forgeStatusLine != null) brd.add(ForgeHooksClient.forgeStatusLine);
            overCopyrightBrandings = brd.build();
        }
    }

    public static void forEachLine(boolean includeMC, boolean reverse, BiConsumer<Integer, String> lineConsumer) {
        final List<String> brandings = getBrandings(includeMC, reverse);
        IntStream.range(0, brandings.size()).boxed().forEachOrdered(idx -> lineConsumer.accept(idx, brandings.get(idx)));
    }

    public static void forEachAboveCopyrightLine(BiConsumer<Integer, String> lineConsumer) {
        computeOverCopyrightBrandings();
        IntStream.range(0, overCopyrightBrandings.size()).boxed().forEachOrdered(idx->lineConsumer.accept(idx, overCopyrightBrandings.get(idx)));
    }

    public static String getClientBranding() {
        return "forge";
    }

    public static String getServerBranding() {
        return "forge";
    }

    public static IResourceManagerReloadListener resourceManagerReloadListener() {
        return BrandingControl::onResourceManagerReload;
    }

    private static void onResourceManagerReload(IResourceManager resourceManager) {
        brandings = null;
        brandingsNoMC = null;
    }
}
```

at this point i managed to rebuild this last .class file changing the client and server branding returns to "elberto", now when i'm running the sdk environment it says "elberto" on the version, but when i'm trying to do the same with the actual minecraft forge file it load everithing and at the end of loading it crash.

I'm pretty sure that this isn't a really good way to do what i want to do, if you know a better way doing a proper working mod i'm listening